# Onclick of different buttons, data should be displayed in mat-table accordingly using angular material.?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to show the sold and unsold classification on click of the buttons as highlighted above.??....

1. All stock button-- should show both sold & unsold
2. Sold button--- should show only the sold classification
3. Unsold button--- should show only the unsold classification.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lYF0.png)

Comment: It would be nice if you also mention what you have tried along with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mat-tabs` [reference](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)

Create components for All Stocks, Sold and Unsold and add your tables inside those components. Now, render those components in mat-tab

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="All Stock"> <app-stock></app-stock> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Sold"> <app-sold></app-sold> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="UnSold"> <app-unsold></app-unsold> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

You can also keep the table itself in mat-tab instead of those app-stock and other components. But, design wise it would be better having tables in separate components